# Создание нового окна для авторизации

Tags: javascript, html, css, всплывающее-окно, окно

Есть сайты https://www.citilink.ru/, https://www.eldorado.ru/. На них есть окно входа/регистрации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форуме уже отвечали когда-то на похожий вопрос и посоветовали создать блок (окно), который при открытии имеет свойство `display: block`, а при закрытии это свойство принимает значение `display: none`. Какие есть другие способы создания нового окна (желательно привести как можно больше способов и как можно подробнее описать каждый из них).

Comment: модальное окно - это самый популярный компонент. каждый лепит его как хочет, кто посложнее, кто попроще. вот например: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOzvl-19fY8. я свой компонент наваял: https://github.com/miptleha/js-modal

Comment: Тут еще зависит от того, какой фреймворк\библиотеку вы используете?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko перечислите возможные варианты.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов  а на https://habr.com/ru/post/440948/ не рекомендуют Модальные окна. Какие есть еще варианты (кроме модальных окон)?

Comment: если от окон отказываемся, то делайте отдельную страницу, как и написано в статье. так тоже хорошо получится.

Comment: Если у вас там angular, vue, react - то будут одни модальные окна. Если у вас там jquery, то будут другие. Если нативный js только, то третьи.